# React router useHistory.push renders component but useState, useEffect not updating without refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am building a basic dummy app for university project which is an International Wallet app.
Each user account can have multiple currency accounts such as GBP, USD etc...
The "/" path is for login, after login the app redirects to the "/myaccount" route which is protected and renders the MyAccount component.
Inside the MyAccount component there is another Switch statement which renders the CurrencyAccounts component which provides a list of all CurrencyAccounts, each list item is a link to the individual account which shows detail.

After successful login works perfect and redirects to MyAccount component and the CurrencyAccounts component renders perfectly except for the useEffect which is suppose to make the API request doesn't update state until after refresh.

So it basically says you dont have any currency accounts when I do, when I refresh the browser, the state updates

Here is the code:

```
//App.js

function App() {

  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(() => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth")));
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(() => {

    if(auth == null){
      return false;
    }
    
    if(auth.isAuthenticated === false){
      return false;
    }

    if(auth.isAuthenticated === undefined){
      return false;
    }

    return true;

  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>Zedland International Money transfer Wallet</h1>
      </header>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route 
              exact path="/" 
              render={() => 
                    <Login setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
                    setAuth={setAuth} auth={auth} /> 
              }
          />
          <Route 
              path="/myaccount" 
              render={() => 
                  <MyAccount 
                      setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated} 
                      setAuth={setAuth} 
                      auth={auth} /> } 
                  />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


//Login.js
const Login = ({setIsAuthenticated, setAuth, auth}) => {

    let history = useHistory();

    const [error, setError] = useState(() => "");

    if(auth !== null && auth.isAuthenticated === true){
        return <Redirect to="/myaccount" />
    }

    const inputStyle = {
        display: 'block',
        padding: '0.5em'
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = document.forms.login;
        
        handleResponse(fetch("http://localhost:8080/authenticate", {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                username: form.username.value,
                password: form.password.value
            })
        }));

    }

    function handleResponse(request){
        request
            .then(response => {

                if(!response.ok || response.status !== 200){
                    setError("Invalid Credentials!");
                }else{
                    return response.json();
                }
                
            })
            .then((auth) => {

                if(auth !== undefined){

                    if(auth.isAuthenticated === true){
                        setAuth(auth);
                        setIsAuthenticated(auth.isAuthenticated);
                    }   
                    
                    localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(auth));

                    history.replace('/myaccount');
                
                }

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setError("Error occured: " + error);
            })
    }

    function handleChange(event){

    }

    return (
        <form name="login" onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{margin: '1em 0'}}>
          <fieldset style={{padding: '1em 0.5em 2em 0.5em'}}>
            <h2 style={{marginBottom: '1em'}}>Log in</h2>
            <input 
                onChange={handleChange} 
                style={inputStyle} 
                type="text" 
                name="username" 
                required="required" 
                placeholder="Enter  your username: "
            />
            <input 
                onChange={handleChange} 
                style={inputStyle} 
                type="password" 
                name="password" 
                required="required" 
                placeholder="Enter your password: "
            />
            <div style={{padding: '1em 0'}}>
                <p style={{color: 'red'}}>{error}</p>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </div>
        </form> 
    )
}

export default Login


//MyAccount.js
export default function MyAccount({setIsAuthenticated, setAuth, auth}) {

    let history = useHistory();

    if(auth === null || auth.isAuthenticated === false){
        return <Redirect to="/" />
    }

    function handleLogout(event) {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        localStorage.removeItem("auth");
        setAuth(null);
        history.push('/');
    }

    return (
        <main>
            <h2>Hello {auth.firstName}!</h2>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/myaccount"
                    render={() => <CurrencyAccounts auth={auth} />}
                />

                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/myaccount/currency-accounts/:id"
                    render={() => <CurrencyAccount auth={auth} />}
                />

            </Switch>
            <button onClick={handleLogout}>Log Out</button>
        </main>
    )
}

//CurrencyAccounts.js
function CurrencyAccounts({auth}) {

    const [currencyAccounts, setCurrencyAccounts] = useState([]);
    const [showCreateForm, setShowCreateForm] = useState(false);
    
    
    function getCurrencyAccounts(){
        //This has been hard coded for convenience, change later!
        Request.get(`/myaccount/${auth.id}`)
            .then((accounts) => {
                setCurrencyAccounts(accounts.currencyAccountSummaries);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error correctly found: " + error);
            })
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {

        if(currencyAccounts.length == 0){
            getCurrencyAccounts();
        }

    },[]);

    return (

        <section>
            {
                (currencyAccounts.length == 0)
                ?
                <h3>You dont have any currency accounts yet!</h3>
                :
                <dl>
                    <h3>My currency accounts:</h3>
                    {
                        currencyAccounts.map((currencyAccount) => {
                            return <li id="currencyAccountSummaryLi" 
                                       key={currencyAccount.currencyAccountId}>
                                       <Link 
      to={`/myaccount/currency-accounts/${currencyAccount.currencyAccountId}`}>
      <dt>{currencyAccount.code}</dt>
      <dd>{currencyAccount.symbol + currencyAccount.balance}</dd>
                                        </Link>
                                   </li>
                        })
                    }
                </dl>
            }   
                <button onClick={() => setShowCreateForm(!showCreateForm)}>
                    Create a new currency account
                </button>
            {
                showCreateForm &&
                <AddCurrencyAccount 
                    currencyAccounts={currencyAccounts}
                    setCurrencyAccounts={setCurrencyAccounts}
                    setShowCreateForm={setShowCreateForm}
                    auth={auth}
                />
            }

        </section>
    )
}

export default CurrencyAccounts
```

*** EDIT 1 ***

Inside the getCurrencyAccounts() function I have tried to console.log the auth object and initially it shows the correct value but then inside the .then(response) method where I would work with the response it says null

```
function getCurrencyAccounts(){

    console.log("1: ", auth);//Shows correct data

    Request.get(`/myaccount/${auth.id}`)
    .then((accounts) => {
        console.log("2: ", auth);//Shows null
        setCurrencyAccounts(accounts.currencyAccountSummaries);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error correctly found: " + error);
    })
}
```

*** Edit 2 ****

Simplified CurrencyAccounts component:

```
function CurrencyAccounts({auth}) {

    const [currencyAccounts, setCurrencyAccounts] = useState([]);
    const [showCreateForm, setShowCreateForm] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {

        if(currencyAccounts.length == 0){
            Request.get(`/myaccount/${auth.id}`)
            .then((accounts) => {
                setCurrencyAccounts(accounts.currencyAccountSummaries);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error correctly found: " + error); //***** Here is the error, exception throwing auth is null *****
            })
        }

    },[]);

    return (

        <section>
            {
                (currencyAccounts.length == 0)
                ?
                <h3>You dont have any currency accounts yet!</h3>
                :
                <dl>
                    <h3>My currency accounts:</h3>
                    {
                        currencyAccounts.map((currencyAccount) => {
                            return <li id="currencyAccountSummaryLi" key={currencyAccount.currencyAccountId}>
                                            <Link to={`/myaccount/currency-accounts/${currencyAccount.currencyAccountId}`}>
                                                <dt>{currencyAccount.code}</dt>
                                                <dd>{currencyAccount.symbol + currencyAccount.balance}</dd>
                                            </Link>
                                    </li>
                        })
                    }
                </dl>
            }   
                <button onClick={() => setShowCreateForm(!showCreateForm)}>
                    Create a new currency account
                </button>
            {
                showCreateForm &&
                <AddCurrencyAccount 
                    currencyAccounts={currencyAccounts}
                    setCurrencyAccounts={setCurrencyAccounts}
                    setShowCreateForm={setShowCreateForm}
                    auth={auth}
                />
            }

        </section>
    )
}

export default CurrencyAccounts
```

*** Edit 3 ****

This is where I assume the bug is, but it is beyond me how it doesn't work. How is the auth variable correct and inside the Request.get shows null

```
useEffect(() => {

        console.log(
           "From currency accounts: ", auth.id);//Works here
        
        Request.get(`/myaccount/${auth.id}`)//Null here
            .then((accounts) => {
                console.log("Accounts: ", accounts);
                setCurrencyAccounts(accounts.currencyAccountSummaries);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("Error correctly found: " + error);
            })

        // if(currencyAccounts.length == 0){
            
        //}

    },[]);


//Custom Request object:
 get: async function(url, opts){

        console.log("From Request.get: ", url);

        let path = `http://localhost:8080${url}`;
        let options = (opts !== undefined) ? opts : {};
        let headers = (options.headers !== undefined) ? options.headers : {};
        
        let response = await fetch(path, {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: this.getAuth(),
                ...headers
            },
            ...options

        });

        try {
            if(!response.ok || response.status !== 200){
                throw new Error({
                    'error': true,
                    status: response.status,
                    ...response
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }

        if(options.return == 'blob'){
            return await response.blob();
        }else if(response.return == 'text'){
            return await response.text();
        }else{
            return await response.json();
        }        
    },

    post: async function(url, opts){

        let options = (opts !== undefined) ? opts : {};
        let headers = (options.headers !== undefined) ? options.headers : {};
        let body = (options.body !== undefined) ? options.body : {};
        let path = `http://localhost:8080${url}`;

        let response = await fetch(path, {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                Authorization: this.getAuth(),
                ...options.headers
            },
            body: body
        });

        try {
            if(!response.ok || response.status != 201){
                throw new Error({
                    'error': true,
                    status: response.status,
                    ...response
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }

        if(options.return == 'blob'){
            return await response.blob();
        }else if(response.return == 'text'){
            return await response.text();
        }else{
            return await response.json();
        }
       

    },

    put: async function(url, opts){

        let options = (opts !== undefined) ? opts : {};
        let path = `http://localhost:8080${url}`;
        let body = (options.body !== undefined) ? options.body : {};
        let headers = (options.headers !== undefined) ? options.headers : {};

        let response = await fetch(path, {
            method: 'PUT',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: {
                Authorization: this.getAuth(),
                ...options.headers
            },
            body: body
        });

        try {
            if(!response.ok || response.status !== 200){
                throw new Error({
                    'error': true,
                    status: response.status,
                    ...response
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }

        if(options.return == 'blob'){
            return await response.blob();
        }else if(response.return == 'text'){
            return await response.text();
        }else{
            return await response.json();
        }
        
    },
```

Result from Console.log:

[Console log screenshot, can't explain why its null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ntb3.png)

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: before refreshing, add a console.log in the getCurrencyAccounts function and check if `auth.id` has correct value

Comment: did you try to debug the Switch statement to see if you get the correct details you need? from there foward you shoud do a debug to understantd if is geting right until you useEffect ... and why you dont start your useState of setCurrencyAccounts before you use in your hardcoded statment?

Comment: I just checked and edited the question at the bottom, apparently the auth value is correct at the start of the function but then inside .then() when I get the response it says null?

Comment: auth is showing as null, which is strange because before I do history.push/history.replace the state is correct, when the Component renders its also correct but somehow inside the Request.get().then() method, it shows null, Anyway I have simplified the code so it should be easier, now Im trying to debug it

Comment: @theMyth if yo change the ${auth.id} to the id like '`/myaccount/1`' it works?

Comment: No it doesn't I tried. Same thing happens, It still throws an exception saying auth is null, that's strange, because it is not null outside of useEffect, only inside the then method it says null

Comment: ok then try one thing, on ` 'useEffect(() => { your code },[auth.id]);'`

i think that the useEffect is not seeing the update of auth

Comment: Tried that too, and no difference. Its really strange as just one line above the code the auth property is not null and then inside the Request.get('/myaccount/${auth.id}') is null

Comment: is that request get right?..here my exemple   useEffect(() => {
    id && getSById(id).then(setS).then(() => setLoading(false))
  }, [id])

Comment: Yes, inside Request.get it is throwing an exception auth Is null, after refresh it works. Thats strange as it works one line above. Is that a separate useEffect function you want me to try?

Comment: I have even checked my Request object and the get method and done console.log from there, the variable is showing.

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully bit more clear and also added a screenshot from the console

Comment: mate i just remenber, test this :  `Request.get("/myaccount/"+auth[0].id)`" or "`Request.get("/myaccount/+auth[].id)`

Comment: It was working perfectly before I started implementing the redirects, so I can't help but think its something else weird that is going on I tried its undefined The same thing works, I find it strange how its null

Comment: i whant to help but i'm stuck too... try to go some steps back

Comment: Thank you, You are very kind, I will check and try debug it all over. Its very strange how is it null before refresh, it works perfectly after refresh, so it has to be something to do with redirect or something I guess. I am trying to debug it with debugger

Comment: i think is somting about the useEffect

Comment: useEffect is asynchronous so I realise its not the first thing that fires, but it worked before I added react redirects, The exact code was working pefectly when I was doing a conditional redirect without history.push & Redirect

Comment: I have checked the prop is not null anywhere, in every line of code up until I make the API request, then it somehow says its null and throws an exception. Im going to update the question

Comment: I managed to get it to work, I can answer my own question now, but I want to figure why

Comment: By removing the <Redirect component in the login page this problem disappears, I guess that extra redirect is having the effect somehow, I want to figure why

Comment: remove return <Redirect line and replace that line  for 'history.push("/")'

Comment: That didn't make any difference, I think the state is updating too many times with the redirects/push state, but Im trying to get it to work. Basically because my default landing page is either login form or home page, basically all routes are protected unless logged in

Comment: you have solution for the moment?

Comment: Hey, Yes I fixed it, I should have posted. But I still dont completely understand why it is happening like that. Basically the state update causes the component to rerender and then it is redirected to the MyAccount component before history.push('/myaccount') is called, and it was redundant, so by updating the state, it automatically worked, but I dont know how solid that is, I can post it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time the state changes the whole component re-renders from where the state is defined. In this case the parent App Component.

When setAuth(auth) is called, the whole component re-renders going to the redirect line in the login.js before it hits history.push('/myaccount')

Which shouldn't really be an issue but for some reason by removing history.push('/myaccount') after setting the state and local storage, it all works

function handleResponse(request){
request
.then(response => {

```
                if(!response.ok || response.status !== 200){
                    setError("Invalid Credentials!");
                }else{
                    return response.json();
                }
                
            })
            .then((auth) => {

                if(auth !== undefined){

                    if(auth.isAuthenticated === true){
                        localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(auth));
                        setAuth(auth);
                    }   
                    
                }

            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setError("Error occured: " + error);
            })
```